# Add a custom Bokeh widget using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, bokeh

In the [Adding a Custom Widget](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions_gallery/widget.html) section of the Bokeh documentation, it states that custom widgets can be implemented using either JS or CoffeeScript. [This Bokeh issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6481) indicates Bokeh is switching over to TypeScript.

Can we implement custom widgets in TypeScript now? Will CoffeeScript implementations continue to work going forward?

Answer (score 0):

All of the built in widgets are now in typescript (as of 0.12.16 at least) so no problems there at all. There haven't been any stated plans to completely remove coffeescript and a good 10% of the bokeh repo is still in it so you should be safe for a good while. If writing anew and given the choice then go for typescript, and if its an existing widget you could always use something like decaffeinate to convert to raw js if you don't want to leave it.

If you're still worried though you can ask the core devs on either [the gitter](https://gitter.im/bokeh/bokeh?source=orgpage) or [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!forum/bokeh).